# Jotforms integration issue with submission

Tags: php, html, css, jotform

I integrated Jotforms into a landing page more for the purpose of storing data. However, I'm having an issue after submission. Every time someone submits a form, jotforms has this error thing that is like a new page, but it still actually submits the data to jotforms. I'm trying to have it once they submit either just goes back to top of page or a popup where it says Thank you for submitting or something like that

```
<?php

// $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb+srv://tribit_proxy_user:uM3JLpGJr58GeVf@cluster0.j6oly.mongodb.net/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-115czw-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ShopCK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </link>
</head>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submission_id'])) {


    // $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

    // $document = ['contactName' => $_POST['contactname'], 'contactEmail' => $_POST['contactemail'], 'contactPhone' => $_POST['contactphone'], 'businessName' => $_POST['businessname'], 'businessPhone' => $_POST['businessphone'], 'businessPhysicalAddress' => $_POST['businessphysical'], 'businessEmail' => $_POST['businessemail'], 'businessWebsite' => $_POST['businesswebsite'], 'facebook' => $_POST['facebook'], 'twitter' => $_POST['twitter'], 'instagram' => $_POST['instagram'], 'youtube' => $_POST['youtube'], 'linkedin' => $_POST['linkedin'], 'businessCategory' => $_POST['businesscategory'], 'businessDescription' => $_POST['businessdescription'], 'additionalComment' => $_POST['anyadditionalcomment'], 'businessImages' => $_POST['uploadany']];

    // $bulk->insert($document);
    // $result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('test.user', $bulk);

    echo "<h1>DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY</h1>";
}
?>

<body>
    <div class="shopck-banner">
        <div class="banner-logo-container">
            <img alt="" src="./images/Logo.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2 class="banner-title">ShopCK is coming soon!</h2>
            <h6 class="banner-description">Providing a directory to discover and support local businesses.</h6>
        </div>
        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#form-container">
            <div class="banner-btn-container">
                <button class="banner-btn">Register now</button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="instagram-link"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/k_wicksy/"><i style="color: white; margin-right:6px" class="fa fa-camera"></i>@k_wicksy</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="form-container">
        <script type=" text/javascript" src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/211297864375264"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="shopck-footer">
        <a target="_blank" class="powerd-by-section" href="https://www.tribitsoftware.ca/">

            <h6>Powered by Tribit Software</h6>
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="./images/Tribit.png">
            </div>

        </a>
        <p class="copyright">@Copyright 2021 ShopCK</p>
    </div>
    <?php

    ?>
</body>

</html>


html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.shopck-banner{
    background-image: url('./images/ShopCKHomeDark.png');
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.banner-logo-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.banner-logo-container img{
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.banner-title{
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: -0.00833em;    
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.banner-description{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: 0.0075em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.banner-btn-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.banner-btn{
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-top: 32px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    min-width: 64px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: background-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,border 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.75;
    border-radius: 4px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.banner-btn:hover{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

.instagram-link{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    right: 16px;
}
.instagram-link a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.instagram-link a:hover{
    color:#ddd;
}
.shopck-footer{
    color: #939596;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: #1c1d1f;
}
.powerd-by-section{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #939596;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.powerd-by-section:hover{
    color: #ddd;
}
.powerd-by-section h6{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: 0.0075em;
}
.powerd-by-section img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.copyright{
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.43;
    letter-spacing: 0.01071em;
}
```